# Mongoose expiry

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the below schema:

```
ip: String,
port: Number,
msgboard: [{
   date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        expires: 120
        },
   msg: String
}]
```

I want the messages to be removed automatically after 120s from creation. But the above delete's the whole document and not just that subdoc from msgboard.
I have been doing it using cron and running a function, but the code seems too untidy. Is there any inbuilt way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should try this, its working. 
I have created two schemas for this problem

**msgboard schema :**

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var msgboardSchema = new Schema({
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        expires: 120
        },
    msg: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('msgboard', msgboardSchema);
```

**Main Test Schema :** In which reference of msgboard is stored

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var TestSchema = new Schema({
    ip : { type : String },
    port : { type : String },
    msgboard : [{type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'msgboard'}]   
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Test', TestSchema);
```

As msgboard is separate from Test, this will only remove msgboard subdocumet from Test after 120s and not whole test document.

Comment: is the msgboard array in the TestSchema will be modified after removing msgboard ?